# Could there be a badge for answers/questions which don't require editing?

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Badge request: "Practically Perfect in Every Way"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36154/badge-request-practically-perfect-in-every-way)

I think, given the recent pushes to inspire edits, that it would be useful to reward users whose question and answers are upvoted 10 or more times **and are left unedited for the first six months of existence.**  In other words, the users didn't rush, posted cogent, well thought out answers / questions which were **never** edited (not by anyone -- not even themselves -- perhaps we could ignore the five min grace period ;O) ) within the first six months.

I think this could be a silver badge.  I think it could be awarded multiple times.  I think a nice title would be 'Well Spoken'.

However -- these are just suggestions, I make too many simple typos to ever earn it...  Feel free to edit this post with updated suggestions!

Comment: Not sure about this one. It would seem to discourage edits, even when they would be beneficial.

Comment: @Michael It wouldn't discourage edits, but it would encourage people who get edited to yell at the editor about how the edit wasn't significant enough to cost them a badge

Comment: I disagree on the premise that it might discourage small personal edits, but then someone else could make improvements and provide incentive to be more careful next time.

Comment: @Michael - I agree with the latter half of your statement, but note that when M. Tibbits says "no edits", he's including the post's author. Those folks shooting for this badge might avoid editing their posts.

Comment: A post that has never been edited is not necessarily a good one; it could be a post that is so bad to discourage users to edit it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think this is a good idea, and that's coming from someone whose posts (as far as I know) rarely get edited by others and would definitely be a candidate for this badge.

I agree that not having to have your post edited is a desirable quality and one we want to encourage, but I worry that a badge for such would have far *less* desirable side effects, along the lines of those mentioned by Michael and Michael in the comments. Namely that it would seem to discourage edits, even when they might be beneficial, and it would make posters more likely to be upset at editors who cost them a badge.

If a potential editor might feel bad about editing because it'd cost someone a badge, then that is a huge problem. Edits are good; we want to encourage them. We even allow anonymous users to [suggest] edits now, in accordance with this same principle. No one's perfect.

Also consider that not all edits are merely grammatical. Some add tags, some update content that has changed over time, some add additional information. None of those things suggest any failing on the part of the original poster, and all of those edits should be encouraged wherever possible.

Comment: Alright, you won me over Cody.  I agree.

Answer (score 5):

There are ton of posts out there that have never been edited, but need it badly.  They just haven't been got to yet.  One of the reasons I suppose they just implemented the new old-post-edit badges.