# Badge suggestion: Encouraging people to write good titles

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Badge request: "Practically Perfect in Every Way"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36154/badge-request-practically-perfect-in-every-way)

**Badge purpose**: encouraging people to write good titles by themselves: informative, and not purposefully unclear or overly eye-catchy. Something which is needed, especially on StackExchange!

**Who would apply for the badge**: anyone with more than *N*(to be chosen) questions…

- with a ratio upvote/views > *R*% (the title provides a good description of the problem),
- with more than *V* views (the title is interesting enough),
- <s>whose title has not been edited by somebody else</s>. (maybe not a good idea, see comments).

Numbers (*N*, *R*, *V*) have to be chosen adequately (using preexisting data).

**Examples:**

- Headline Maker badge (5 questions with 5% upvote ratio and 50 views each)
- Gazetteer badge (10 questions with 6% upvote ratio and 75 views each)
- Journalist badge (15 questions with 7% upvote ratio and 100 views each)

Better naming for those badges are welcome.

What do you think?

Comment: See [Could there be a badge for answers/questions which don't require editing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103311/could-there-be-a-badge-for-answers-questions-which-dont-require-editing) for some reasons why this could backfire.

Comment: @Michael: Well if a title need to be edited, it will be edited anyway. Nobody will care for the badge. Not even the post author, he/she will have other occasions…

Comment: Stéphane, you have an optimistic view of human nature, and of people's desire for shiny round things.

Comment: @Michael: Ok just remove this condition… (not really required to encourage people writing good titles, but maybe the chosen numbers should be different without it…)

Comment: Now it sounds like it overlaps heavily with *Good|Great Question* and *Popular Question*, though at a lower threshhold.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you could implement this well without manual review.  I think having badges that can't be automatically awarded will add too much manual work to the system.  There's already more manual work to do, than is getting done.

Answer (score 3):

This always reminds me of [something I read once](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4HTPCJFsZ8).

The problem with the *`<contents>` has not been edited* badges is that that is not a good measure of quality. I know I've seen a number of titles which I've seen which might have used editing but never received it. I've definitely seen titles which were so bad that they were beyond redemption.

I've also heard of people who prowl about the stacks looking for a comma to change.

This means that there are many which are good but would not be recognized, and many which are bad which would be. That strikes me as exactly the type of middle-management style thinking that SO wants to avoid.