# 'Articulate' badge for perfect presentation

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

I propose the `Articulate` badge, to be awarded for posting `[n]` questions which

- remain up for `[given amount of time]`
- receive no edits
- receive at least one up-vote
- receive at least one answer with an up-vote

Basically, a reward for perfect presentation.  This will encourage well-crafted questions, which are valuable because:

1. They help the poster to [Ask the Duck](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/).
2. They elicit [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Negatively, this could promote spurious editing with the malicious goal of preventing someone else from receiving the award.  Spurious editing is actively discouraged so perhaps we're safe.

Comment: Sounds related to [those badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges), so I don't think we need yet more of these. Nice idea though.

Comment: By "remain up" do you mean that they are not put on-hold? (or perhaps not deleted?)

Comment: By "remain up", I mean they're valid questions - not put on hold, not deleted.  And they've had time to accrue edits.

Comment: Oops!  Fairly close duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36154/259449.  And, the downsides are well discussed.  I will delete this post pretty soon.

Comment: Well, you can't delete this now since it has positive-score answer. You can close as duplicate if you really think it is a dupe though.

Comment: Let's close the other as a dupe of this.  That one doesn't include upvotes in the equation, which seems a necessary part of being truly considered articulate.  I would also not count edits in the grace period.  Not because I use them all the time, just because they're only effective for minor touch-ups, not saving-throw reworkings.  Also, you might want to include an accepted upvoted answer as a requirement.  If you truly are articulate, then your question is eminently answerable, and that answer will be worthy of praise.

Comment: @Won't:  "Let's close the other..."  If the proposals are different, neither is a dupe, so why close the other one?

Comment: @Smandoli eh, they cover the same ground.  I'd say the other was incomplete, whereas this is a better version of what the other was attempting to suggest.

Answer (score 5):

This would probably get awarded to far too many posts that are simply neglected. A question that no one has bothered to edit and doesn't get many views.

Lack of downvotes and lack of edits aren't very strong indicators that a post is well-written.