# Is it a good manner to have a nice question/answer without any edit history?

Tags: discussion, edits

I know it's recommended to edit a post if there's improvement. But as a personal preference, I'm often proud of having an upvoted question or answer without a revision history, and I'll admire if someone has one. So at last is it a commended practice to be so?

Comment: This reads like `Is it a good practice to ask a good question first time?`, of course it is but ultimatly makes no diffrence, people make mistakes, this is unavoidable. Post the best you can, first time. I really don't see this is on topic here as it is just  personal opinion and mine is diffrent, I don't mind an edit to fix my mistakes, I am grateful someone took the time.

Comment: I think questions/answers which are not bad are already rewarded with the lack of downvotes which could probably never be retracted even after future improvements. Other than that, I don't find any sort of admiration on not editing content, as there is almost always something that can be improved.

Comment: I downvoted this because the last sentence looks like it could do with an edit.

Comment: If someone posts nonsense and then edits the post into shape, just to be the first one to post an answer (the ["fastest gun in the west"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) issue), then this would be bothersome, but in all other cases: doesn't matter.

Comment: The lack of a revision history may also signify that the post is so bad that no one thought it was worth the time to fix it...

Comment: @yannis Then it should also have a nice large number of downvotes (and hopefully delete votes) :D.

Comment: @yannis Looks like you're wrong. I mean "an **upvoted** post without editing".

Comment: Related discussion: [Badge request: “Practically Perfect in Every Way”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36154) and its linked posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: It doesn't matter.

---

If a question or answer is good, it can be posted and never be edited. On the other hand, it can also be edited to make it even better, or updated as things change over time.

Editing is **not** a bad mark, by any means. If someone, for their own personal reasons, see this as something bad, it's purely their own personal matter/opinion and it should not affect anyone else.

Good manner is putting the quality of contents above anything else, so even if you consider post without edits as some ultra achievement, and see something needing edit in your post, best thing to do is edit and enjoy the fact you helped some other people by doing so.

Answer (score 5):

Not really. **It can also be interpreted as lazyness, or more extremely, arrogance**. I have seen many answers which produced a subsequent discussion between the author and the asker (and maybe other users). The **comments provide clarifications to the answer**, and could well be **summarised** by improving the answer and then deleting the comments. That is very efficient as it might save time to other readers, who are not really interested in the nuances of a conversation but on a precise answer. **A good user would edit the answer to incorporate clarifications or further information from comments**. A lazy one would not be bothered. An arrogant would actively avoid editing posts.

Comment: **needs** more **bold**.

Comment: @yannis I use bold to indicate the core bits that you can read by themselves and still understand the statement.

Comment: Bold is a tool for emphasis and should be used as sparingly as possible. You're overemphasizing, which severely hurts readability.